# jQuery UI Dialogr() plugin destroy event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

lately I've been working with the jQuery UI dialogr() plugin, though I've met a problem regarding the destroy and the re-call of the $(foo).dialogr(args) function, because it is not creating the dialogs again after being destroyed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#init').click(function(){
        $('.test').dialogr();
    });
    $('#destroy').click(function(){
        $('.test').each(function(){
            $(this).dialogr('destroy');
        })
    });
});
```

The following is a simple dialog snippet code that I'm using to explain what happens

```
<a href="#" id="init">generate</a>
<a href="#" id="destroy">destroy</a>
<div class="test" title="test dialog 1">
    test dialog 1
</div>
<div class="test" title="test dialog 2">
    test dialog 2
</div>
```

Explanation: After destroying the dialogs, pressing generate wont generate them again, without returning any errors, any opinion is appreciated. Sample http://jsfiddle.net/2zGWZ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Engineer, I've came up with a solution which can be easily implied into the dialogr() plugin, just open ui.dialogr.js with an editor and search for:

```
this.element.unbind('.dialog').removeData('dialog')
```

Then replace it with

```
this.element.unbind('.dialogr').removeData('dialogr')
```

Problem will be solved for more complicated dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `dialogr` property from `.data()` object:

```
     $(this).dialogr('destroy');
     delete $(this).data().dialogr;   //deleting 'dialogr' property
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2zGWZ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine using ui `dialog` as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2zGWZ/2/).
Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: I checked with ui dialog too, incase it was a UI bug, but it's a plugins bug.